# Desenvolver sistema de temas em PHP ou JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, cms, temas

Estou desenvolvendo um CMS (Content Management Sustentável) como o WordPress, usando PHP e JavaScript. Praticamente todas as funcionalidades já foram implementadas, mas estou tendo dificuldades em desenvolver um sistema de temas. Alguém pode me dar uma luz ?

Comment: Sustentável ??? Emite menos carbono?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para criar um tema, o conceito é o mesmo de um e-mail marketing, ou seja, você tem um layout que possui marcadores que serão substituídos pelo conteúdo personalizado na hora do disparo.

Aqui tem um tutorial que mostra como criar um tema do zero em PHP

https://pt.broculos.net/2008/03/how-to-make-simple-html-template-engine.html]

Se você não quiser criar algo do zero, pode dar uma olhada no Smarty, que é um sistema de template com muitos recursos

https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/pt_BR/what.is.smarty.tpl

Comment: Obrigado amigo, o post da broculos me ajudou muito.